# RestKit mapping XML to Core Data

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, restkit

I working with it for two days... I want get remote xml then parse/map it to core data. I have read bunch of tutorials, so at this moment I can connect with local server (yyuupii!), get xml, but I have problem with mapping. I get

> -[RKObjectLoader canParseMIMEType:] Unable to find parser for MIME Type 'application/xml'
>
> -[RKObjectLoader isResponseMappable] Encountered unexpected response with status code: 200 (MIME Type: application/xml -> URL:
>   http:///list.xml -- http:/// --
>   http:/// -- http:///) 2012-10-24
>   14:13:12.201 Sierpien[4650:907] Error
>   Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t
>   be completed. (org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain error 4.)"

Could you gave me some advice I will be thankful.

My XML

```
<packs>
    <pack>
        <cover>cover.png</cover>
        <info>Jakis.adres.pl</info>
        <link>Opis</link>
        <name>wrzesień</name>
        <price>5.00</price>
    </pack>
    <pack>
        <cover>cover2.png</cover>
        <info>Jakis1.adres.pl</info>
        <link>Opis31</link>
        <name>wrzesień12</name>
        <price>15.00</price>
    </pack>
</packs>
```

My Entity

```
@interface Pack : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * link;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * price;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * info;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * cover;

@end
```

My Implementation

```
- (id)initClient
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        RKObjectManager *client = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:[RKURL URLWithString:@"http://10.1.1.5:8888/"]];
        NSLog(@"I am your RKObjectManager singleton : %@", [RKObjectManager sharedManager]);
        client.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeXML;

        RKObjectMapping* listMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Pack class]];
        [listMapping mapKeyPath:@"cover" toAttribute:@"cover"];
        [listMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
        [listMapping mapKeyPath:@"info" toAttribute:@"info"];
        [listMapping mapKeyPath:@"link" toAttribute:@"link"];
        [listMapping mapKeyPath:@"price" toAttribute:@"price"];

        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:listMapping forKeyPath:@"packs.pack"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadPacks {
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/list.xml" delegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I throw away RKObjectManager, now I connect with RKClient, get xml with

`[[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/list.xml" delegate:self];`

Then I parse Xml by GDataXML, fill Pack with that parsed data. It works.